# How to copy font color from one textbox to the other?

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I have tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
var x = Slides[1].Shapes[1].TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB;
Slides[1].Shapes[2].TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB = x;
```

Comment: `it didn't work:` => doesn't compile? Doesn't set the color?

Comment: It doesn't set the color. It does get the numeric RGB value, but it doesn't show in a slide.

Comment: @Ivan I just tested it myself and your code works. It must be something else.

Comment: @Ivan Would you mind adding more information?

Comment: Is the code running while PPT is in normal view or slideshow view?  Often, changes made to shapes while in slide show view don't appear until the slide is refreshed (.View.GoToSlide(Index)) and sometimes not even then.